# Call a PHP script from an Angular application

Tags: php, angular, amazon-ses

I am working on an Angular 5 project and I want to be able to be contacted by users using a contact form.

Here is a simple contact form using MDBootstrap `contact.html`

```
<form action = "send_mail.php" method="post" >
<div class="container">

<p class="h5 text-center mb-4">Contactez nous ! </p>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control" mdbActive>
    <label for="form3">Prenom Nom</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" id="form2" class="form-control" mdbActive>
    <label for="form2">Adresse mail</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" id="form32" class="form-control" mdbActive>
    <label for="form34">Sujet</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil prefix grey-text"></i>
    <textarea type="text" id="form8" class="md-textarea" style="height: 100px" mdbActive></textarea>
    <label for="form8">Votre message</label>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-unique waves-light" action = "test.php" mdbRippleRadius>Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
</div>
```

I choose to use Amazon SES Services. So I downloaded their SDK and opted for the PHP solution.

It works fine using the terminal and the command `php send_mail.php`

But when I click on my button the PHP Script isn't called. I thought that it was a simple call using an HTML element but even when I try to call a simple script like `echo'test'` it still doesn't work and I don't get why.

If you have any idea it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example using a service to perform a GET request to your script:

I will be using angular CLI here.

First, generate a new service:

```
ng generate service <service name> --module=<module name> //replace service name and module name
```

Open the newly generated .ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class serviceName{

    private url = 'http://localhost/path_to_php_script';
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    }

    performGetEx():Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
    }
}
```

In you then inject this in your component that will be calling:

```
import {ServiceName} from 'path/to/service.ts';

...
//component's constructor
constructor(private  serviceName:ServiceName){}

sendEmail():void{
    this.serviceName.performGetEx().subscribe(...);
}
```

In your markup:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-unique waves-light" [click]= "sendEmail()" mdbRippleRadius>Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i> 
    </button>
</div>
```

Remember to change `serviceName` to whatever you supplied when generating the service.

You can also you angular's `[(ngmodel)]` to bind input to a model or type if you want to supply user input, you would each input to bind, then pass the object or values to your service and perform either a get request using query params or a post request. See https://angular.io/guide/http for documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very useful ! Thanks to you I think I'm on the good track.

The only thing I don't get is what's the value of `private url = 'http://localhost/path_to_php_script';` ? I don't get where is my `localhost:4200` located.

The consequence is that I have an error in Chrome `GET http://localhost:4200/send_mail.php 404 (Not found)`

Comment: Since PHP is a server side language, you still need something an interpreter. You need a server running to execute the PHP. Install WAMP/MAMP and have apache or some other middleware listening.

Answer (score 1):

So I used @Kisaragi method which was very useful. I think I'm almost there but it still doesn't work for me.

Using his method I had the following error : `GET http://localhost:4200/send_mail.php 404 (Not found)`.

So I created a `php` folder in my `assets` folder and added the `send_mail.php` in it.

In my component `send-mail.service.ts` I updated the path of the file like that :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SendMailService {

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    performGetEx():Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get<any>('../assets/php/send_mail.php');
    }
}
```

and in my component `contact.component.ts` I did the following thing in my `suscribe()` method

```
sendEmail():void{
     this.sendMailService.performGetEx().subscribe((v => console.log('value: ', v)),
     (e => console.log('error: ', e)),
     (() => console.log('the sequence completed!')));
 }
```

So when I go to chrome consol I don't get the `GET` error anymore but catch the error on my `suscribe` function.

Here is the error :

`error:  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/php/send_mail.php", ok: false, …}`

Do you understand this error ? The Http status seems to be Ok...

Comment: Have you found how to solve this?